# How can I pass in multiple subject lines into this notifier?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I've built out a notifier that sends emails that are triggered from the model it relies on. Everything works. I just would like to know how I can pass a different subject (eg: Friendly Reminder - Invoice Due, Warning - Your account will be suspended) for the different methods I have set up.

```
  def send_notice(manual_invoice_id)
    @invoice = Billing::ManualInvoice.find(manual_invoice_id)
    @subscription = @invoice.subscription
    filename = "Invoice - #{@invoice.due_on.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")}.pdf"

    attachments[filename] = { mime_type: 'application/pdf',
                              content: @invoice.generate_pdf! }
    mail(to: @invoice.subscription.owner.billing_emails.join("; "), subject: "These should all be different") do |format|
      format.text
      format.html
    end
  end

  def suspended_email_1(manual_invoice_id)
    send_notice
  end

  def suspended_email_2(manual_invoice_id)
    send_notice
  end

  def suspended_email_3(manual_invoice_id)
    send_notice
  end

  def suspended_email_4(manual_invoice_id)
    send_notice
  end

  def suspended_email_5(manual_invoice_id)
    send_notice
  end
end
```

I tried using a switch/case statement but that seems to only add noise. I wonder if I should pass another parameter to the `send_notice` method.

Comment: The old action mailer had `subject` method you could call, I think it's gone. You could add a method like `def subject(subj) @subject = subj  end` and call it from each method before `send_notice` and use `subject: @subject` in the `mail` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add an extra parameter to the send_notice method? Like this:

```
 def send_notice(manual_invoice_id, subj)
    @invoice = Billing::ManualInvoice.find(manual_invoice_id)
    @subscription = @invoice.subscription
    filename = "Invoice - #{@invoice.due_on.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")}.pdf"

    attachments[filename] = { mime_type: 'application/pdf',
                              content: @invoice.generate_pdf! }
    mail(to: @invoice.subscription.owner.billing_emails.join("; "), subject: subj) do |format|
      format.text
      format.html
    end
  end
```

Then you can call it differently from each of your methods:

```
def suspended_email_1(manual_invoice_id)
    send_notice(manual_invoice_id, "Friendly Reminder - Invoice Due, Warning - Your account will be suspended")
end
```